# how to use python to set hdfs directory quota

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

all,I wanna set the hdfs dir quota using python.

when set quota,we should use `hadoop dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota $QUOTA $DIR`

I found a python lib called pyhdfs (https://github.com/vbarter/pyhdfs) ,it can control many hdfs operations but no quota operations.

if I have to create a dir using python:

```
fs = hadoop.HadoopDFS("username","password","ugi",64310)
print fs.getDefaultBlockSize()
fs.disconnect()
```

so how to set the quota of a dir in hdfs?
Is there a similiar way to do that?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the pyhdfs module, but if it doesn't do what you want, you can just call out to a subshell.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["hadoop dfsadmin", "-setSpaceQuota ugi 64310"])
```

This is how I prefer to do hadoop-type management from within a python script. It has its downsides, but it gets the job done.